# kendo bind HTML elements to grid selected row/dataItem

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have the following situation (using KendoUI):

I have a grid binded to a datasource.
When I select a row in the grid I invoke its "change" event to get the selected dataItem e show its values through other HTML elements.

Something like the following:

```
$("grid-element").kendoGrid({
    change: setElements
});

function setElements() {
    var grid = $("#grid-element").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

    $("#span-field1").text(selectedItem.field1);
    $("#span-field2").text(selectedItem.field2);
    $("#span-field3").text(selectedItem.field3);
}
```

My question is: is it possibile to achieve the same through MVVM or a better KendoUI model binding solution?

Comment: I'm not familar with the MVVM stuff, but fyi - in the change event, you can use 'this' to access the grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I have found the following solution:

```
=== JAVASCRIPT ===
var vm = kendo.observable({
    gridSelectedItem: null,

    _field1: function() { 
        return this.get("gridSelectedItem.field1"); 
    },
    _field2: function() { 
        return this.get("gridSelectedItem.field2"); 
    }
});

$("#grid-element").kendoGrid({
    change: function(e) {
        var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
        vm.set("gridSelectedItem", selectedItem);
    }
});


=== HTML ===
<span data-bind="text: _field1"></span>
<span data-bind="text: _field2"></span>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there you are on the right track,

Here is what I can suggest you to try:

```
=== JAVASCRIPT ===
var vm = kendo.observable({
    gridSelectedItem: null    
});

$("#grid-element").kendoGrid({
    change: function(e) {
        var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
        vm.set("gridSelectedItem", selectedItem);
    }
});


=== HTML ===
<span data-bind="text: gridSelectedItem.field1"></span>
<span data-bind="text: gridSelectedItem.field2"></span>
```

It should be slightly more compact.

Comment: Yes it is thank you. But actually there are situations where I need to apply a custom format to data (for example "kendo.toString(value, "p1")"), so I prefer to mantain the field inside the model.